# DHTMLX Grid Pulling Additional Data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, dhtmlx

I am trying to build an app for users to submit their work times in but am having trouble with pulling additional data into the grid.

Eg: If a user were to type in there employee code of 0000 into the Employee Code Column the Employee Name Field would need to update to read "John Doe" All this data is stored in databases on the back end and I have been able to access it on refresh eg. If the page is reloaded after the new row has been created and the data is present it will pull the correct data in, but i do not want them to have to refresh the page to do this. How can I pull in the extra data after the cell has been updated.

The Grid is created on the page with JavaScript as follows:

```
timesheetGrid.setColumnIds("Column Names, Column Names");
            timesheetGrid.setImagePath("codebase/imgs/"); //set the image path for the grids icons
            timesheetGrid.setInitWidths("70,100,100,100,70,100,150,100,70,70,100,70,70,*,*");  //sets the initial widths of columns
            timesheetGrid.setColAlign("center,center,center,center,center,center,center,center,center,center,center,center,center,left,left");  //sets the alignment of columns
            timesheetGrid.setColTypes("edn,ro,dhxCalendar,ro,edn,ro,ed,ro,ro,ro,ed,edn,ch,txt,ro"); //sets the types of columns
            timesheetGrid.setColSorting("str,str,date,date,str,str,str,str,str,str,str,str,str,str,str");  //sets the sorting types of columns
            timesheetGrid.setDateFormat("%Y-%m-%d"); //Set the Date Format to be used in the Grid
            timesheetGrid.attachHeader("#text_filter,#text_filter,#text_filter,,#text_filter,#text_filter,#text_filter,#text_filter,#text_filter,#text_filter,#text_filter,#text_filter,,,");
            timesheetGrid.setColumnHidden(3,true);
            timesheetGrid.enableEditEvents(true,false,true);
            timesheetGrid.init();
            //timesheetGrid.makeFilter("WeekEnding",0); //TODO: Add Filter For Week Ending
            //this.lockRow(id, true); //Make Specific Row Read Only TODO: Non Active Week Rows Read Only
            timesheetGrid.load("data/timesheets.php");
            var dpg = new dataProcessor("data/timesheets.php");
            dpg.enableDataNames(true); // will use names instead of indexes
            dpg.init(timesheetGrid);
```

PHP is used to pull data from the correct avenues

```
require("../codebase/connector/grid_connector.php");//adds the connector engine
    $conn = new GridConnector($res,"MySQL");             //initializes the connector object
if ($conn->is_select_mode()) {//code for loading data
    SQL Code is HERE
}else { //code for other operations - i.e. update/insert/delete
    OTHER SQL CODE IS HERE
}
```

As the Data is sensitive I cannot display any of it sorry for any inconvenience.
Any Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data you're providing is XML you can attach an event to your grid and call this grid.updateFromXML("data/timesheets.php");
This will parse and paint the whole grid information

If you're looking to update just the row you updated you can send via GET the id of the row and it will only parse and paint the row you're sending
grid.updateFromXML("data/timesheets.php?for=" + row_id));

Full Code would be something like this:

```
dpg.defineAction ("update", myUpdate);
function myUpdate(tag){
    timesheetGrid.updateFromXML("data/timesheets.php?for="+tag.getAttribute("sid"));
    return true;
}
```

If the data you're retrieving is not XML formatted, I'm afraid you would need to update the values from the row manually via the same event.

Comment: Data is coming from a MySQL database

Comment: The database is irrelevant, your timesheets.php I assume generates an XML file since you're not sending the format parameter, so the solution must work.

Comment: The contents of time sheet php are above the only code missing is the sql statement as I am not able to give out our data structure. I will try using the update from xml command above and post my findings

Comment: Just forget what I said, since you're using the GridConnector(grid_connector.php) it is XML.but it is transparent to you, so above code will definitely work

Comment: entries dont seem to be pulling in the new data

Comment: This is the Code im using:
var dpg = new dataProcessor("data/timesheets.php");
    dpg.enableDataNames(true); // will use names instead of indexes
    dpg.setVerificator(2,not_empty);
    dpg.init(timesheetGrid);
    dpg.defineAction("update", getMoreData);
    
    function getMoreData(tag) {
     timesheetGrid.updateFromXML("data/timesheets.php?for="+tag.getAttribute("sid"));
     return true; 
    }

Comment: Sorry Just had to add the define action on insert as well

Comment: Great, I thought you were only updating so my answer only included the update action, but it works for every action! Glad it helped.

Comment: I have now run into the issue where I am using data validation and as such data is not submitted until all the fields are filled in is there a way I can pull this extra data as they fill in the fields?

Comment: I think you can try adding the updateFromXML, in the grid's onEditCell event, when they finish editing a cell or on the dataProcessor onValidationError i think it is.